# How do I use framebuffer as texture for the next frame in moderngl?

Tags: python-moderngl

I'm trying to animate Mandelbrot set slow step-by-step appearance. Here is my approximate code for fragment shader:

```c
#version 330

uniform sampler2D previousIteration;
in vec2 uv; /* from -1 to 1 */

out vec4 color;
layout (location=1) out vec4 zValue;

void main() {
  vec4 state = texture(previousIteration, uv);
  float newReal = state.x * state.x - state.y * state.y + uv.x;
  float newImag = 2 * state.x * state.y + uv.y;
  float newAbs2 = newReal * newReal + newImag * newImag;
  if (newAbs2 < 4) {
    color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  } else {
    color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  }
  zValue = vec4(newReal, newImag, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Then I have to output `color` framebuffer to the screen in `moderngl-window` (a trivial task) and also pass `zValue` framebuffer as `previousIteration` texture for the next frame (I have no idea how to do it).

I've seen various examples like [slimes](https://github.com/Leterax/slimes), but it uses `image2D` rather then texture; for my purposes I'd be interested in using texture. I'd also prefer to use simple saving with `zValue = ...` rather then using `imageStore`.

Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73240765/how-to-get-render-data-from-headless-context-in-moderngl) and answers I can copy framebuffer content to a numpy array and then send the array to GPU as texture; however, this includes copying to RAM and back to GPU, which is something that should be avoided.

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24597083/10700729) states I do not "copy FBO to texture"; however, I don't actually understand what does it mean.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27582687/10700729) using `glCopyTexImage2D()` function seems to be what am I looking for, however, it's C and I can't find something like that in moderngl python API; moreover, the function seems to be deprecated or rarely used in modern code.